# Php Error On Client Server

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a form on php that writes the result on a .txt file.

What happens is that on my server all is working good, but on another server there is the following error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/alertme/public_html/mavala/form.php:43) in /home1/alertme/public_html/mavala/form.php on line 52

The code I am using is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $new_content = "\r\nNome: " . $name;
      $new_content .= "\r\nEmail: " . $email;
      file_put_contents('emaillist.txt', $new_content, FILE_APPEND);
      print_r(error_get_last());
      header('Location: thank-you.html');    //This is line 52
    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

The link of the server with the error is: http://trendalert.me/mavala/form.php

After filling the form and submit, the php writes the result on the .txt file but does not show the thank you page: http://trendalert.me/mavala/thank-you.html

Again, on my side it´s all working, but on the clients´server is not.

Comment: Remove the whitespace before `<?php ` and omit the closing `?>` tag

Comment: ...and remove the print_r that also generates output

Comment: I suppose it "works" you correctly because you turn off error mesages.

Comment: I suggest you to change `header('Location: ...')` to `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://.../">';` to handle all errors like that may be occured. EDIT: I posted an answer too.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
```

is your issue, its sending white space which sends the headers.

Make sure that `<?php` is the very first thing in a php file

also on a production server, them warnings should be suppressed

Comment: There is also a print_r in there.

Answer (score 0):

When using header you must not have any black space before your php open tag and any output before the header call. This behavior can change on different configuration and php versions.

So, remove all blank spaces and your print_r and your problem will be fixed !

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $new_content = "\r\nNome: " . $name;
  $new_content .= "\r\nEmail: " . $email;
  file_put_contents('emaillist.txt', $new_content, FILE_APPEND);
  print_r(error_get_last());
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=thank-you.html">';   //This is line 52
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $new_content = "\r\nNome: " . $name;
  $new_content .= "\r\nEmail: " . $email;
  file_put_contents('emaillist.txt', $new_content, FILE_APPEND);
  $errors = error_get_last();
  if(empty($errors)){
  header('Location: thank-you.html');    //This is line 52
  exit();
  } else {
   print_r($errors);
  }
}
?>
```